# Excel and Capital IQ Plug-in

Tags: excel, plugins

Is there a way to refresh Capital IQ Plug-in when programmatically open Excel file. Any explanation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A little bit late, but maybe this can help.

In the Capital IQ plugin, go to settings --> Data --> Automatically retrieve data

Make sure that this box is checked.

This will automatically refresh all data in that particular worksheet.

Something to note, ensure all Excel instances are closed (with Task Manager) before opening your file - Capital IQ plugin tends to "live" in the first instance and will throw an error when you try to refresh.